# Proof with limit of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I assume that $X$ is an integrable random variable, i.e. it satisfies $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$.

I consider now the following expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>K\}}]
$$
for some positive $K$.

Now I want to show that
$$
\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>K\}}] = 0
$$
which seems to be intuitive. However, I want to know how to show it formally.

I wonder also if I need some additional assumptions to show it.

Comment: Immediate from DCT.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it might be kind to spell that out  as the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Comment: Could you rewrite it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n=|X|1_{\{|X|>n\}}$. Obviously, $X_n$ is bounded from above by $|X|\in L^1$ by assumption. Pointwise is $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=0$ almost surely. Now, DCT states that

$$lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}(X_n-0)dP=0. $$

This can be rewritten by the definition of expectation as $EX_n\to 0$ what is precisely what you wanted to show.

Comment: Is it true that $X_n$ is bouned from above. I only know that $X$ is integrable, e.g. if $X = B_t$ then it is integrable but it is not bounded.

Comment: Bounded from above in $L^1$. This means that there exists random variable, which is a.s. larger than $X_n$ AND is integrable. Such a variable exists, it is precisely $|X|$.